# Recursive Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm trying to wait for a bunch of promises to complete. I know I can do this with `Promise.all`, but I can't figure out what to do when one of those promises pushes a new promise into the promise list.

Example:

```
asyncFunction(...).then(result => {
    // do something
});


asyncFunction(...).then(result => {
    for(let row of result) {
        asyncFunction(row);
    }
});


console.log(promises.length); // 2
await Promise.all(promises);
console.log(promises.length); // 5
```

Where `asyncFunction` is something like:

```
const asyncFunction = (...args) => {
    let result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(...args, (err, rows, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(rows); 
            }
        });
    });
    promises.push(result);
    return result;
};
```

What's happened here is that the first two calls to `asyncFunction` push promises into my `promises` array, so `promises.length` is 2. However, after waiting for them to complete, the 2nd one pushes a bunch of new promises into the array after `Promise.all` has already evaluated that array, so they're not awaited.

So, how can I wait for all the promises, plus any new ones? Simply calling `await Promise.all(promises)` twice would work in this example, but this could go on ad infinitum.

Comment: Don't push to the pool at arbitrary times. Wait until the pool is filled, `then` call `Promise.all` on it. Don't pool everything together in one array if you need to push at distinct times, rather call `Promise.all` multiple times.

Comment: @Bergi The new promises are created as a result of a previous async result.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37801654/1048572) help?

Comment: @user2864740: So? Then those new promises should be `Promise.all`'d, and be chained to the previous async result via `then` so that you get a promise for them.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I think that's more or less the same question. The posted solution could probably be made slightly more efficient by not re-evaluating the already checked promises though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know when all Promises are Resolved in a dynamic "iterable" parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801654/how-to-know-when-all-promises-are-resolved-in-a-dynamic-iterable-parameter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a recursive all function that re-evaluates the status of the list after each iteration:

```
function recursiveAll( array ) {
    // Wait for the promises to resolve
    return Promise.all( array ).then(function( result ) {
        // If no new promises were added, return the result
        if ( result.length == array.length )
            return result;
        // If new promises were added, re-evaluate the array.
        return recursiveAll( array );
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't need to store `prevLength`, you can just use `result.length`

Comment: Wouldn't `return recursiveAll(array.slice(result.length))` be more efficient? i.e. only check the new elements.

Comment: No, then we would have a new array with a new reference, and any items added to the original array would not be available in the next recursion.

Answer (score 2):

That's the problem with functions that have side effects.

Your code is a bit to abstract to give you a moe precise answer, but I would reccomend you to completely drop the `promises`-Array.

```
const asyncFunction = (...args) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(...args, (err, rows, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(rows); 
            }
        });
    });
}
```

and

```
asyncFunction(...).then(result => Promise.all(result.map(row => asyncFunction(row))) );
```

As far as I understand your intentions, this should result in a nested structure of Arrays within Arrays, in the worst case, wich now only has to be flattened to get ALL values, and those wich are triggered by the previous ones.

Comment: I tried doing it that way for a bit, it gets so messy. Its fine for a simple loop, but if you're doing a bunch of random stuff, then you have to collect up all these 'loose' promises so that you can return a `Promise.all` at the end. I just wanted something automatic; I don't care when all the individual promises complete, just when they're *all* done.

Comment: I agree, but due to the level of abstraction in your code-sample, I can't give you a better example/answer. Maybe you can show the concrete Problem, so we can discuss this on some real code.

Comment: _That's the problem with functions that have side effects._ Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think simply replacing `Promise.all` with this should work fine:

```
while(promises.length) {
    await promises.shift();
}
```

Comment: `await` is not exaclty ES6.

Comment: @Bergi No... it isn't, I'll retag the question. Although my original question already had an `await` in it. I guess an await-less version would be nice too.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it will evaluate all promises in *sequence*, not in *parallel*.

Comment: @TbWill4321 What do you mean by "in parallel"? JS is single-threaded. The 3rd promise might resolve before the 1st and then the first iteration of this loop will hang longer than it needs to, *but* we're waiting for *all* the promises to complete anyway, so the *total* time remains unchanged, no? I guess the difference is if there's a rejection: `Promise.all` would bail sooner.

Comment: While JS is single-threaded, it does not synchronously wait for a Promise before moving to the next.  A good example is multiple AJAX calls, which can be done in parallel.  The point is starting as many async calls at the same time as possible, not waiting for the last before moving on to the next.

Comment: @TbWill4321 Indeed, but in my scenario, I'm firing them all off in parallel, I'm only awaiting them in sequence.