# How can I modify the array passed to Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

My node.js class is recursively loading files from the file system asynchronously.

Other methods of my class are not valid until all of the files have finished loading, so I defined an array of promises, and do `Promise.all()` on the array before executing methods that depend on the loading being complete.

As the code discovers each file or directory, it adds a new promise to the array so that the array eventually contains one promise for each directory scanned and each file loaded. I have verified that this is working as designed.

The problem is that `Promise.all()` seems to only wait on promises that are already in the array when it is called, and does not wait for promises that are added to the array after `Promise.all()` is called, so the promise returned by `Promise.all()` is resolved before all of the files have been loaded.

Yes, I did make sure that new promises are added to the array before the current promise is resolved to avoid that race condition.

Assuming that I can't use `Promise.all()` in this situation, what is the best alternative?

Comment: Related: [How to know when all Promises are Resolved in a dynamic “iterable” parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37801654/4642212).

Comment: please show your snippet

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is the same problem I have but I could not find this question by searching.

Comment: @bikeman868, You should get all the promises a head of time.

Comment: You cannot get the list of promises ahead of time because it is recursively (and asynchronously) traversing the directory structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the link to [How to know when all Promises are Resolved in a dynamic "iterable" parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801654/how-to-know-when-all-promises-are-resolved-in-a-dynamic-iterable-parameter). Using info from this thread I was able to come up with a working solution as follows:

```
  private readonly loadingPromises: Promise<any>[];

  private async finishLoading(): Promise<void> {
    var completedCount = 0;
    while (this.loadingPromises.length != completedCount) {
      var waitCount = this.loadingPromises.length;
      await Promise.all(this.loadingPromises);
      completedCount = waitCount;
    }
    this.loadingPromises.length = 0;
  }

  async somePublicMethod() {
    return this.finishLoading().then(() => {
      //... do stuff here
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should traverse the file system's tree first to get all the files' paths and store them in an array, then `Promise.all` that array.

Something like this:

(i am using lodash)

```js
async function getPaths(dir) {
  const files = [];
  const promises = [];
  const contents = await fs.readdir(dir);

  for (const content of contents) {
    if(_.endsWith(content, '.js')) { // only get JS files
      files.push(path.resolve(dir, content));
    }
    else {
      promises.push(getPaths(path.resolve(dir, content)));
    }

  }
  let subDirFiles = await Promise.all(promises);
  subDirFiles = _.flatten(subDirFiles);

  return _.union(files, subDirFiles); // contain all files paths from a root `dir`
}
```

Comment: I can't do this because the code recursively (and asynchronously) traverses the directory structure. This loading process is kicked off in the constructor, and the other methods of the class are called whilst the loading is in progress.

Comment: May i ask what are you trying to achieve exactly? Why some methods of the class are called whilst the loading is in progress ?

Comment: This class loads some files into memory in its constructor, then provides some methods that return information based on the contents of those files. The methods that return information must wait until all of the files have been loaded.

Comment: The class is quite big and we have restrictions on pasting code on public forums.
I would have to come up with a contrived example that demonstrates the issue, however my original question explains the situation quite well I think.