# Adding a Promise to Promise.all() after they all finished

Tags: javascript, promise

Assuming I have a

```
function(){
  ....
  return Promise.all([p1,p2])
}
```

And I want to instead return a promise of p1, p2, p3, with p3 starting only after p1 and p2 are done. What would be the best way?

Would the following work:

```
function(){
  ....
  return Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(
    (p) => {
      return Promise.all(p.push(p3));
    })
}
```

Anything special to handle rejected promises?

Comment: Why do you want to use `p1` and `p2` again after they resolve? The callback could return `p3`: `.then(() => p3)`.

Comment: @jabaa — The goal might be to end up with an array containing the resolved values of p1, p2 and p3. (It would likely be easier with async/await though).

Comment: `push` returns the new length, so that's not useful. You probably want something like `p.concat([p3])` which would work.

Comment: Promises generally "start" as soon as they are created. Presumably the `then` handler would be responsible for actually creating `p3`, not just returning it using `Promise.all`. I wrote a similar answer here: [How to know when all Promises are Resolved in a dynamic "iterable" parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37801654/1426891)

Answer (score 0):

What you had would work conceptually, but not practically because `p.push()` returns the new length of the array, not the array.  So, you could fix it like this:

```
function(){
  ....
  return Promise.all([p1,p2]).then((values) => {
      values.push(fn3());  // start operation 3 and add p3 to the array
      return Promise.all(values);
  });
}
```

This also assumes that you only start the operation that returns p3 after the first `Promise.all()` returns.

I would personally prefer to use `await` like this, but it gives the same result:

```
async function someFunc() {
    ...
    const values = await Promise.all([p1, p2]);
    values.push(fn3());  // start operation 3 and add p3 to the array
    return Promise.all(values);
}
```

This works because `Promise.all()` accepts an array of promises or values or a mix of the two.  For values in the array (anything other than a promise), it just immediately adds them to the results array (no need to wait for a promise).

---

Or, perhaps a little simpler to read where the code is a bit more self descriptive for what you actually want to do, you could just  do this:

```
async function someFunc() {
    ...
    const values = await Promise.all([p1, p2]);
    values.push(await fn3());   // start operation 3
    return values;
}
```

This last option would be my favorite.

Comment: Added a third option which I think is the cleanest.

Answer (score 0):

#### Spread syntax

If you prefer the format you've already got, you could alternatively use the [array spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to do this:

```js
function(){
  ....
  return Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(
    (p) => {
      const p3 = f3(); // start p3
      return Promise.all([...p, p3]);
    })
}
```

It's worth noting that this will create a *copy* of the array, rather than pushing a new item to the existing array. Keep this in mind if you're accessing that original array of two promises elsewhere in your code. If you're dealing with a large number of promises, this could also be a performance issue.

#### Error handling

Take note that [the documentation for `Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) states:

> It rejects when any of the input's promises rejects, with this first rejection reason.

So whichever promise rejects *first* will trigger a reject for `Promise.all()` *and only that rejection is a provided as an argument for `catch((err) => { ... })`.*

Comment: Note, the spread syntax copies data whereas `.push()` just adds onto the existing array without copying the prior array.  Perhaps irrelevant for small arrays (not irrelevant for large arrays), but as a matter of general programming I like to avoid making extra copies when a simple solution avoids the extra copy.

Comment: True, although because we're not working with primitive types here, the new array is assigning by reference (as far as I'm aware). It's not quite a _deep_ copy.

But it is an important thing to note, thank you for pointing that out. :)

Comment: It's a shallow copy, but still a newly created array that copies the values of the prior array.

Comment: Correct, that's a good point.